# Infinite complete linear hypergraphs with edges of different sizes

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

Is there an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ with a collection of subsets ${\cal E}$ of $\kappa$ with the following properties?

1. $\bigcup {\cal E} = \kappa$,
2. $e \neq f \in {\cal E}$ implies $|e \cap f|=1$
3. $|e|<\kappa$ for all $e\in {\cal E}$, and
4. not all members of ${\cal E}$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: $\kappa =\omega$?

Comment: If you want that all members of $\mathcal{E}$ have different cardinality, then $\kappa$ cannot be a successor cardinal, but any limit cardinal will do the trick. Furthermore, $\vert\mathcal{E}\vert \leq \kappa$, and if $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible, then you get $\vert \mathcal{E}\vert = \kappa$.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesSchürz for your comments! Can you give me a hint on how to construct a set $\cal E$ of finite subsets of $\omega$ that have properties 1-4? If you put it into an answer, I'll accept it and we can close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition $\omega \setminus \{0\}$ into infinitely many finite sets $I_n$ such that $\vert I_n \vert=n$. Define $\mathcal{E}:=\{I_n \cup \{0\} \colon n \in \omega\}$.